# Apache and TLS mode - password in plain text in wireshark

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ldap, starttls

My apache.config:

```
 LDAPTrustedMode TLS

    LDAPTrustedGlobalCert CERT_BASE64 /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.cer


        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "login to continue"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative on
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://test.local/dc=test,dc=local?sAMAccountName
        AuthLDAPBindDN "bindtest@test.local"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "pass"
        #require valid-user
        AuthLDAPSubGroupAttribute member
        #AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
        AuthLDAPSubGroupClass group
        Require ldap-group CN=awx,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=test,DC=test,DC=local
```

This works fine, user can login, but when i observe traffic in Wireshark, i notice that password of bindtest@test.local user is sent in plain text and that name of user who tries to login is also shown, also port 389 is used.

When i change  `LDAPTrustedMode TLS` to `LDAPTrustedMode SSL` then password is not shown and comunication to Domain controller uses port 636.

I read that SSL/636 port is deprecated in Apache, that's why i want to use SSL over port 389.Documentation says that STARTTLS first uses unencrypted connection first and once communication is established, further data exchange is encrypted.

**Edit based on some comments**

Changing LDAPTrustedMode to `STARTTLS` still shown password of `AuthLDAPBindDN` user in plain text

Comment: Try: `AuthLDAPURL "ldap://test.local/dc=test,dc=local?sAMAccountName" STARTTLS`.

Comment: just use AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://test.local/dc=test,dc=local?sAMAccountName, that will keep working and don't downgrade the connection unvoluntarily

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, still the same, password of bind user is shown in plaintext